# ProxyPass or ProxyPassReverse redirect is adding my port to traffic

Tags: apache, redirect, proxypass, maximo

I have a virtual host in Apache that is giving me the fits. I am trying to point a secure external URL to a Maximo Java Virtual machine within our network via Apache.
Here is my virtual host from the conf file.

```
   <VirtualHost 5.5.5.5:443>
    ServerName maximolink.mydomain.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLEngine on

    # Turn on SSL
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
    # Path to DigiCert Certificate
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
    # Path to gafoc certificate
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/certs/star_gafoc_com.crt
    # Path to SSL key generated during creation of CSR
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/maximolink.mydomain.com.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia full
    EnableSendFile On
    EnableMMAP On

    RewriteEngine On

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    # Turn on the proxy
    ProxyPass / https://internalmaximoserver.mydomain.com:9451/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://internalmaximoserver.mydomain.com:9451/

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ssl-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ssl-error.log

    <Location />
            #ProxyPassReverse /
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The results are, I can go to When I go to :
https://maximolink.mydomain.com/maximo/

Some traffic begins to pass between the servers (images, html), but eventually the file paths begin to request and pass as 
https://maximolink.mydomain.com:9451/maximo/--  I am not sure how to stop the 9451 from being attached to the URL during the passing of the traffic.

Comment: Are you using WebSphere? the port may be part of the URL constructions per WebSphere or the Java application itself. You can change the port that is referenced, but I'm not sure if you can remove it completely from the URL... http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/27/changing-the-default-port-in-websphere-application-server/

Comment: I am using websphere, but I need the specific port 9451 to be used the default SSL port is already used on that server. Websphere works internally when I go to the link https://internalmaximoserver.mydomain.com:9451/maximo. However, when using Apache to try https://maximolink.mydomain.com/maximo I get

Comment: port 9080, 80, 443 as bound by default to the maximo.ear application. You can verify in the SystemOut.log when maximo.ear is first started. If you changed the port to 9451 in WebSphere, shouldn't your network team handle the visibility of this server to the outside? Why are you using Apache?

Comment: So, apache is handling the visibility to the server to the outside. I am using apache to reverse proxy Maximo outside of the network. This is for a Birt reporting only server so I can point all Maximo report calls to maximolink.mydomain.com and direct all traffic to the BROS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I had to adjust the conf file by having it listen on 9451 and set a named virtual host. Here is the updated code:
`

```
Listen 9451
NameVirtualHost 5.5.5.5:9451
<VirtualHost 5.5.5.5:443 5.5.5.5:9451>
    ServerName maximolink.mydomain.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLEngine on

    # Turn on SSL
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
    # Path to DigiCert Certificate
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
    # Path to gafoc certificate
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/certs/star_gafoc_com.crt
    # Path to SSL key generated during creation of CSR
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/maximolink.mydomain.com.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia full
    EnableSendFile On
    EnableMMAP On

    RewriteEngine On

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    # Turn on the proxy
    ProxyPass / https://internalmaximoserver.mydomain.com:9451/

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ssl-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ssl-error.log

    <Location />
            ProxyPassReverse /
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

`

This seems to work. Good Luck!